# Can repeated failed login attempts using ValidateCredentials cause user to get locked out?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I had to implement a security solution that validates user credentials against an ldap/AD server.

The code is something like this...

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
{
    return context.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
}
```

Will repeated attempts by the user to login using this method, cause their account to be locked out based on the AD/ldap rules?

Thank you,
Tony.

Edit: I am looking for the answer to know if I have to handle the user lock out or if the auth server will do it for me.

Comment: Too afraid to try and find out?  ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it only cares about invalid logins, so assuming they don't change their AD password while signed on in an active session that it starts hammering the server with bad credentials I don't see how it could impact anything.

Comment: @The Evil Greebo, I may have too.
@Chris Marisic: I am asking to know if I need to handle the lock out or if the auth server will. <- add to question.

Comment: Yes, it will lock out the account.   Is there a better method of just *testing* whether a username & password is valid, without it unexpectedly locking out a user ?  I'm using this in a WCF service attached to an iPhone app... and I really don't want the app to lock the users out, when they change their password every 6 months  (and the app still has the old one).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, if your application has bad PW information, A/D will lock the user out.  A great example of this happening in practice is with Windows services running on user accounts...user changes pw and the service isn't updated and soon the user is locked out.